# Voice modulation in live phone call in iOS 6+

Tags: ios6, voice, phone-call

I want to  do voice modulation in live phone call meaning while conversation is happening , I want to do voice modulation. I saw ios apps which do voice modulation after they record the voice. I also checked one application named "[VoiceChanger](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/call-voice-changer-intcall/id535048805?mt=8)" , which adds the different voice in the ongoing calls. That call happens over VOIP as I can call any number from ipod touch & it is also written in their app description. For ipod touch we don't have calling functionality. Correct me if I am wrong.

Is it possible to do **Voice modulation in live call in iOS** ? If yes , any reference or library is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get anything even using VOIP calls??

Comment: No. I didn't search using VOIP calls as I that was not my requirement. Sorry